# Displaying DB query data as a table

Tags: c#, .net, database, datatable

I am bit new to C#. I am working on a Database application and I need to execute a query say a SELECT and load it in to some sort of table view. Then I want to double click on a result and get it loaded to my original data entry form. Can someone tell me the way that I should follow? Dont waste your time to add coding etc. Simply the steps would be enough. A link to a good resource is also be OK :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) and [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) to retrieve data from the DB.  Assuming SQL server, otherwise other DB providers are also available and implement the same API.

For Window Forms look at [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx), you can bind a DataTable to it and it will display the data in the DataTable

[You can find an example over here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Loot at some samples:

- Database Viewer (in sources) http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/MyDbViewerSite.aspx
- Also look at this http-support.microsoft.com/kb/308247

Future Readings:

- Data Access Application Block @MSDN
- Various Object Relational Mappers (LinqToSQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate etc)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/FillDatafromdatabasetabletoListView.htm

Answer (score 0):

[ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937699.aspx)

> SUMMARY: ADO.NET is a data-access
>   technology that enables applications
>   to connect to data stores and
>   manipulate data contained in them in
>   various ways. It is based on the .NET
>   Framework and it is highly integrated
>   with the rest of the Framework class
>   library. The ADO.NET API is designed
>   so it can be used from all programming
>   languages that target the .NET
>   Framework, such as Visual Basic, C#,
>   J# and Visual C++.